# ImportError: cannot import name NullHandler

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to deploy a hello-world type app on Elastic Beanstalk. Just about everything seems to work, packages are installed, etc. up to the point where mod_wsgi attempts to retrieve the "application" object from wsgi.py. At that point, the following appears in the logs (once in the logs for each unsuccessfuly HTTP request):

```
mod_wsgi (pid=6114): Target WSGI script '/opt/python/current/app/myapp/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
mod_wsgi (pid=6114): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/opt/python/current/app/myapp/wsgi.py'.
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/opt/python/current/app/caserails/wsgi.py", line 20, in <module>
     application = get_wsgi_application()
   File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 14, in get_wsgi_application
     django.setup()
   File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup
     from django.utils.log import configure_logging
   File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/log.py", line 16, in <module>
     from logging import NullHandler  # NOQA
 ImportError: cannot import name NullHandler
```

[Link to concurrent AWS Forum Post.](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=165432&tstart=0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much trial and error, the (immediate) problem was solved by removing python [logging](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/logging) from requirements.txt and rebuilding the environment.

I do not yet fully understand why this is a problem.  On my local machine, I'm able to install logging and run Django without error. I suspect as vikramls pointed out that something weird is happening in the intersection between mod_wsgi, the baselineenv in which mod_wsgi executes, and the virtualenv in which my app operates.

But, at least for now, I'm fixing this error by not including "logging" in requirements.txt when deploying Django 1.7 on Elastic Beanstalk.

Answer (score 3):

I had similar problem and in my case the issue was that for some unrelated project I created logging.py file in home folder and when I ran something in home, it was importing this file instead of the real module.

You can check which file is being imported like this:

```
import logging
print(logging.__file__)
```

I fixed it by deleting logging.py I created previously.

Answer (score 3):

The `NullHandler` is only available on Python version 2.7+. You could create the `NullHandler` yourself on an `ImportError`:

```
import logging

try:
    from logging import NullHandler
except ImportError:
    class NullHandler(logging.Handler):
        def emit(self, record):
            pass

logging.getLogger(__name__).addHandler(NullHandler())
```

More information about `logging.NullHandler`: https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.handlers.html#logging.NullHandler.

Comment: Thanks @Roald it worked for us. The Trick is we had to go to the location: C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\urllib3 and here in init file we just pasted the code where it is inside to try and except block

Answer (score 1):

[NullHandler](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.handlers.html#nullhandler) was introduced in version 2.7. Are you sure you are running 2.7 on your server?

Comment: Sure is famous last words. . . But, I did put some syslog statements into my wsgi.py file to try and see this (e.g. syslog.syslog('sys.executable: {}'.format(sys.executable));
), and when I run the python that it returns (e.g. -V) it says that my python executable is 2.7.5.

Comment: Why does your traceback have `/opt/python/current/...` path and `/opt/python/run/venv/...` as well? Some sort of virtualenv misconfiguration?

Comment: I *think* that all the different python-paths are an artifact of how AWS's EB environment sets up virtualenvs to run under mod_wsgi.  [Here is some documentation from Google on it.](https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/VirtualEnvironments).  
There are three sources of code potentially in play. . . The AWS Elastic Beanstalk Baseline Environment (which shouldn't be being accessed here directly, but is instead the "environment" within which the mod_wsgi interpreter runs), the Virtual Environment (which is in venv), and my app (which is in current)

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue while creating a build for python 2.7 with PyInstaller.So, I uninstalled logger from my ENV.else you can also remove the package name from the requirement.txt.
This approach solves my issue [Happy Coding:)]