# pip ImportError: cannot import name NullHandler

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, pip

when I try to see the pip version, the error is generated

pip --version

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    from pip._internal.locations import USER_CACHE_DIR, get_src_prefix
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/locations.py", line 18, in <module>
    from pip._internal.utils import appdirs
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/utils/appdirs.py", line 16, in <module>
    from pip._internal.utils.compat import WINDOWS, expanduser
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/utils/compat.py", line 17, in <module>
    from pip._vendor.urllib3.util import IS_PYOPENSSL
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    from logging import NullHandler
ImportError: cannot import name NullHandler
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ImportError: cannot import name NullHandler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26939308/importerror-cannot-import-name-nullhandler)

Comment: Do you have any script or module called `logging`? It seems something overshadow standard `logging`.